# Quero usar exceptions do php para ignorar um erro que acaba encerrando o script

Tags: php, exceção, terminal, linha-de-comando

Quando o usuário não tem o cliente instalado eu recebo um erro que encerra o script. Como ignora-lo com *exceptions* e continuar o script?

> PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home/usr/master/app/src/handlers/IqHandler.php on line 257
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getChainKey() on null in
>   /home/usr/master/app/src/libaxolotl-php/state/SessionState.php on line
>   177

Comment: Você precisa dar mais detalhes sobre isso ...

Comment: A começar pelo código. Porque ninguém vai responder `try{}catch(exception){//faz nada};`. Lembre que perguntas genéricas só merecem respostas genéricas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A função `foreach()` espera um objeto iterável como uma `stdclass` ou um `array`.

Para evitar o `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`, apenas crie um código consistente verificando se o parâmetro é iterável e possui os dados necessários para a execução da rotina.

Exemplo para o tipo `array`:

```
$n = 0;
if ($n == 1) {
    $arr = array(1, 2, 3);
}
// Aqui usamos is_array() pois esperamos um array.
if (isset($arr) && is_array($arr) && !empty($arr)) {
    foreach ($arr as $v) {
        echo $v;
    }
}
```

Exemplo para o tipo `stdclass`

```
$n = 0;
if ($n == 1) {
    $arr = (object)array(1, 2, 3);
}
// Aqui usamos is_object() pois esperamos um stdClass
if (isset($arr) && is_object($arr) && !empty($arr)) {
    foreach ($arr as $v) {
        echo $v;
    }
}
```

Quanto ao segundo erro, provavelmente é consequência do primeiro erro. Uma reação em cadeia.

Resumindo, apenas crie códigos com um fluxo consistente pois não há como ignorar um erro do tipo fatal error. Esse nível de erro pode até ser ocultado mas não poderá impedir que o compilador interrompa a execução.

Note que quando o PHP roda em modo CGI, um fatal error é despachado no output mesmo que `display_errors` esteja como *OFF*.

Caso ainda tenha dúvida, faça o teste:

```
$arr = 1;

try{
    foreach ($arr as $v) {
        echo $v;
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Não funfa para fatal error.
}
```

O `try/catch` não captura erros do tipo *fatal error*.

Comment: "O try/catch não captura erros do tipo fatal error." Obrigado