# Qual a forma mais segura de se obter erros no PHP?

Tags: php

Tem vários métodos para se obter os erros no PHP, mas já vi muita gente falando que não é seguro eu exibi o erro padrão do PHP na tela já que facilita eles a terem informações do servidor.

Gostaria de saber qual o método mais seguro sem problemas?

Comment: A forma mais segura é não cometer erros :P. Exibir erros na tela não problema nenhum desde que seja no ambiente de desenvolvimento, na produção vocês pode optar por gravar em arquivo de texto ou banco de dados, para algo muito crítico um sms/email.

Comment: @rray mas pela pergunta, ele quer obter erros kkk :) - Diria que uma forma segura é fazer o erro direto no fonte, aí é bem seguro que você vai obter um erro. Vinicius, brincadeiras à parte, o Log do PHP é o lugar correto para ver os erros da sua aplicação. E isso normalmente já vem funcionando.

Comment: @Bacco eu notei o paradoxo haha :D, gostaria de obter sucesso, dinheiro e saúde.

Comment: Aqui já tem algo que pode ajudar a configurar a aplicação: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/106562/por-que-usar-error-reporting-com-display-errors-e-display-startup-errors

Comment: Dou a dica de utilizar Try Catch e customizar suas mensagens de erro, que serão apresentadas ao usuário, em uma classe.

Comment: @Diego Dias alguma dica de como fazer isso?

Comment: Ainda bem que, quando usamos um framework (um bom, é claro), não precisamos preocupar com isso ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não há uma resposta exata pois depende do ambiente e circunstâncias.

Uma configuração simples que recomendo é

## Ambiente de desenvolvimento

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('log_errors', true);
ini_set('html_errors', false);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'logs'.DS.'php_errors-'.date('Ym').'.log');
```

## Ambiente de produção

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('log_errors', true);
ini_set('html_errors', false);
ini_set('display_errors', false);
ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'logs'.DS.'php_errors-'.date('Ym').'.log');
```

Obviamente que `date_default_timezone_set()`, define a zona apropriada para o seu caso.

O parâmetro `error_log` indica o local onde as mensagens de erro serão salvas.

Alguns ambientes pode não possuir uma definição no php.ini e isso provoca warning error em algumas versões do PHP. Por isso é bom dfinir, mas não é obrigatório. Quando tiver certeza de que o ambiente já possui a configuração, é redundante especificar novamente.

O mesmo vale para os outros parâmetros. Caso já possuam o mesmo valor no php.ini, então não precisa definir novamente em tempo de execução.

## Por quê a definição depende também de circunstâncias?

Vejamos um exemplo do mundo real. Você possui um sistema legado, construído em 2003, o qual usava scripts daquela época e adaptações diversas até a data atual. Quando executar num ambiente onde a versão do PHP possuir incompatibilidades, na maioria dos casos é inviável consertar um sistema inteiro então fazemos certas "gambiarras" e configurações para dar uma retrocompatibilidade do PHP ao sistema.

Pegando o exemplo dessa resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/106569/4793

A partir do PHP5.4 o seguinte código apresenta erro do tipo `STRICT`:

```
class Foo
{
    public Bar(){}
}
```

Para poder "driblar" essas mensagens de erro de nível `STRICT`, podemos fazer isso:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_STRICT);
```

Isso é o suficiente para prover uma retrocompatibilidade para esse caso específico.

Obviamente, deve-se corrigir todos os tipos de erros que encontrar, desde o mais simples como erros do nível `NOTICE`.

Esteja ciente de que as configurações runtime (em tempo de execução), dependem do ambiente. Há provedores de hospedagem que impõem restrições ou simplesmente bloqueiam o uso ou sobrescrevem os parâmetros. Mais detalhes nessa resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/106569/4793

## Inibidor de erros

Em muitos scripts encontraremos o uso do `@` no início de chamada de funções.

O símbolo `@`, nesses casos, age como um inibidor de erros. Ou seja, possíveis mensagens de erro ou avisos que uma função despacharia, é ocultada.

Normalmente aplica-se para cobrir problemas em sistemas legados (fazer gambiarras) ou também aplica-se em casos legítimos como funções diversas do PHP que disparam erros de forma inexperada, sem um comportamento padrão. Consulte essa pergunta: [Por que dizem que utilizar @ arroba pra suprimir erros é uma má prática?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/84178/por-que-dizem-que-utilizar-arroba-pra-suprimir-erros-%C3%A9-uma-m%C3%A1-pr%C3%A1tica)

## PHP em modo CGI

Há casos onde não consegue-se controlar determinados erros de aparecerem na tela do usuário. Normalmente isso acontece mais quando o PHP é executado como CGI.

No modo CGI, para um erro fatal, quando display_errors está desativado, emitirá  status http 500 "internal server error".

Para testar saber mais detalhes, consulte esse link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/115127/diretiva-display-errors-off-causa-500-internal-error-server

## Exceptions

Para falar sobre exceptions tornaria essa resposta muito extensa. Há diversos links sobre o assunto.

[O que são Exceptions?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/88831/o-que-s%C3%A3o-exceptions)

[Quais são as Exceptions nativas do PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58344/quais-s%C3%A3o-as-exceptions-nativas-do-php)

[Capturar errors e Exceptions do PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2532/capturar-errors-e-exceptions-do-phpv)

[Quero usar exceptions do php para ignorar um erro que acaba encerrando o script](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/116607/quero-usar-exceptions-do-php-para-ignorar-um-erro-que-acaba-encerrando-o-script)

[Quando usar Exceptions no PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/112554/quando-usar-exceptions-no-php)

[Qual exception devo lançar de acordo com cada situação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50053/qual-exception-devo-lan%C3%A7ar-de-acordo-com-cada-situa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

Por fim, é realmente extenso. Numa simples pesquisa encontrará dezenas de casos.

Comment: Existe alguma forma de no ambiente de produção, quando tiver um erro eu mesmo avisar que ocorreu um erro e devo olhar o arquivo de log? Também acha que devo implementar isso na minha pergunta?

Comment: Existem formas de capturar até mesmo fatal error, mesmo quando emitido pelo php-cgi. Mas é melhor fazer uma nova pergunta pois é muito extenso.