# Como exibir erros no ambiente de produção?

Tags: php, log

Estou vindo do embalo desta [pergunta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/117103/qual-a-forma-mais-segura-de-se-obter-erros-no-php).

Existe alguma maneira de, no ambiente de produção, quando ocorrer algum erro eu avisar, que ocorreu o erro e que devo olhar o arquivo de log?

Eu queria que fosse exibido na tela algo mais ou menos assim quando acontece um erro: `Ocorreu um erro, verifique o arquivo de log do sistema`.

Lembrando que venho da pergunta acima, então no caso no ambiente de produção não exibo os erros, apenas guardo-os em um arquivo de log.

Comment: Qual a diferença dessa aqui para aquela? Me parece ser o mesmo problema. Lá você está pedindo meios de receber erros, e o log é só um desses meios. Acho que qualquer resposta aqui caberia lá. Não estou vendo diferença suficiente pra não votar pra fechar.

Comment: @Bacco tipo no caso ele envia o erro para o arquivo de log, porém não avisa nada na página. Eu queria poder escrever na tela algo mais ou menos assim quando acontece um erro: `Ocorreu um erro, verifique o arquivo de log do sistema`.

Comment: Isso já tem na sua pergunta, o que eu não entendi é porque abrir uma nova, se é o mesmo problema da anterior. Sua pergunta não fala nada de log. Naquela mesmo alguém poderia falar da aplicação enviar um email, por exemplo. Ou mesmo gravar a informação num DB de uma página sua de monitoramento, como outro exemplo.

Comment: Eu fiz essa pergunta no comentário, ai carinha que me respondeu falou pra eu abrir uma nova pois era muito extenso pra responder nos comentários

Comment: Me parece que o problema é que você aceitou cedo demais uma resposta que não resolve seu problema, aí diminuiu a chance de outros responderem. Cabem muitas respostas diferentes naquela pergunta sua.

Comment: Hm, desculpa não faz muito tempo que conheci o Stack overflow, acha melhor eu editar minha pergunta lá? Quanto tempo devo esperar você recomenda? E da pra desmarcar como aceito?

Comment: Vou fazer o seguinte, eu não vou votar pra fechar, pois meu voto de fechar duplicata de PHP é instantâneo. Vamos ver o que o resto da comunidade resolve. Se fecharem essa, vc desmarca a aceita daquela, e aguarda mais respostas (ou aguarda o autor da resposta complementar com mais detalhes). Se deixarem aberta, aí fica como está.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No PHP você pode usar a função `set_error_handler()`, e criar sua própria função de tratamento de erros tipo:

```
minha_funcao_trata_erros(){
  //sua lógica
}
set_error_handler("minha_funcao_trata_erros");
```

Neste link você pode ver a documentação da função `set_error_handler()` http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.set-error-handler.php