# Atacar imagem svg com css e include php

Tags: php, html5, svg

Não consigo atacar as propriedades da imagem SVG com include php. Teria um outro método? Sendo que preciso chamar as imagens do banco dinamicamente através do include().
Segue um exemplo funcional, quando a imagem svg está em seu código puro na página em questão.

```
<style>
    #produto > svg > g{ 
      fill: #fff;
    }
</style>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="produto">
            <svg...>
                <g>..</g>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Gostaria que funcionasse desta forma:

```
<style>
    #produto > svg > g{ 
      fill: #fff;
    }
</style>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="produto">
            <?php include('image/my-img.svg');?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Tentei os métodos de inclusão de imagens em sgv ( embed, object) e não obtive sucesso.

Comment: o que exatamente tem nesse arquivo .svg?

Comment: é um vetor, exportei em imagem svg, com as tags, svg, g e path, as quais atribuo propriedades css

Comment: como fez quando tentou com `<object>`?  algo assim não funciona?  `<object data="<?php include('image/my-img.svg');?>" type="image/svg+xml" id="id_qualquer" />`

Comment: Não surtiu efeito, simplesmente não aparece nada, como em <?php include('image/my-img.svg');?>

Comment: o caminho do arquivo está correto?  teste isso: `<?php echo file_exists('image/my-img.svg')? 'ok': 'ng';?>`

Comment: Testei e deu ok! Acho que o include php simplesmente não reconhece a extensão .svg...

Comment: a extensão não tem a ver.. pode ser um .exe que o php inclui o conteú normalmente. Por acaso já experimentou ver o resultado pelo código fonte do browser?..  no chrome , execute normalmente a página php e então pressione CTRL+U.  Provavelmente vc vai encontrar o `<svg>` no código

Comment: pelo código fonte não aparece o svg, da mesma forma no front-end, o código da pagina pára no include e não exibe nada dali em diante...

Comment: Pelo que descreve está ocorrendo um erro do tipo fatal. Configue as opções de log e exibição de erros para mitigar o real problema. Isso pode ajudar a configurar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/117145/4793

Answer (score 1):

Para que você importe a imagem `svg` e ainda tenha acesso as suas respectivas `tags` você pode usar o seguinte código:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents("kiwi.svg"); ?>
```

Assim você poderá referenciar os elementos `SVG` por meio de um arquivo de folha de estilo `CSS`.